# How can I build out child associations on my object in Rails without saving the parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to initialize an object, but I don't want to create the object to the database until the user has click saved. I've gotten this to work with the parent object only, but I can't seem to get my child objects to associate to the parent because I don't have an id yet for the parent object.  What am I doing wrong in the code below? Thanks.

```
  def new

    # Build a new report object with the default type of "draft" and assign it to the player
    report_options = { player_id: @player.id,
                       author_id: current_user.id,
                        position: @player.position,
                            type: "draft",
                       submitted: false }

    @report = Report.new(report_options)

    @skills.where('disabled = (?)',FALSE).each do |skill|
      # On the line below I get an evaluation record with a proper skill id,
      # but report_id is `nil` because I'm guessing the report hasn't been 
      # created yet.  Is there a way to reserve an id for it without actually
      # committing the record to the database until the user saves the record?
      @report.evaluations.build(skill_id: skill.id)
    end

  end
```

Comment: You can't "reserve" an ID without inserting a record into the database. That's how auto-incrementing database columns work.

Comment: @max, yes I understand -- I was just explaining it in that way to try and convey what I was attempting to do.  Though it appears i did it poorly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model of evaluations is not quite clear to me, but basically if you do something like

```
@report.evaluations.build
@skills.where('disabled = (?)', FALSE).each do |skill|
  @report.evaluations << Evaluation.new(skill_id: skill.id)
end
```

it will add objects to evaluations without saving and won't require the report.id to exist at the moment of adding.

Comment: I tried this way but when I do a `@report.evaluations.count` after the assignment it still returns zero.  And the model evaluations is a has_many of Report, and Evaluation belongs_to a skill.

Comment: #count operation works with the database, effectively being mapped to select count(*) SQL operation. It will return 0, since the association is not saved yet. Try using #size or #length instead

Comment: ohhh gotcha thanks! Thanks for the answer. I can see it is populated, but it wasn't showing on my page view because I am guess due to me using a `where` in which I'm dealing with the same situation you already mentioned in that the where wont work as it's not really in the database.  So I'm going to look into how to filter those records in my evaluations now. Thanks again!